# show Processor speed

Tags: linux

I have a server with an AMD Opteron(tm) Processor 246 and a customised Linux kernel (2.6.9-100.ELhugemem) in it. When I check the processor using `dmidecode`, it displays a speed of 2000 MHz, whereas `/proc/cpuinfo` shows a speed of 1000MHz. 
Can anybody explain this and also give me a method to check the current CPU speed?

Answer (score 29):

What you are seeing is probably due to frequency scaling. You can see the minimum, maximum and current cpu frequency by:

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_min_freq
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq
```

(Replace `cpu0` as appropiate).

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by 'frequency scaling' in this context? Do you mean to say that theoretically the processor can run at a higher clock rate but in actuality, to save power, the OS will scale down the frequency?

Comment: @IsaacKleinman: yes, search for Intel SpeedStep, AMD PowerNow, etc...

Comment: if it changes, try `sudo watch -n 1 cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq`

Answer (score 2):

see `cpufreq-info` and `cpufreq-set` in http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_use_cpufrequtils

(may have to possibly install depending on distro)